# Data formats for very large data while preserving data.table functionality

Tags: r, data.table, apache-arrow

I have a script which produces several intermediate data files which would significantly exceed the maximum number of rows in `R` (2^31-1). My system is large enough to store the data (e.g. I can store matrices of that size, but not transform them to long format), but I don't know which file formats can appropriately deal with the data. I want to achieve two things simultaneously: (1) store data with more than 2^31 rows and (2) continue using data.table (or similar) functionality while processing the data.
I know that there are methods for achieving (1) like the `arrow` package, but my understanding is that these file formats then require a whole other way of processing the data, preventing (2). From what I understand the `bit64` package cannot be used to 'cheat' R and get index numbers for more rows.
Basically I have written a whole bunch of code already building on data.table functionality, and I would prefer to continue using that instead of rewriting everything. Is there a solution for that?
Sorry no reproducible example (not sure it's appropriate for this question).

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but have you tried using `dtplyr` with a lazy arrow table? Other than that, what options do you have for either (a) splitting into smaller groups, or (b) working in a database?

Comment: I have not tried ```dtplyr```, but I will look into it. I'm not very well versed with the dplyr syntax, but it sound promising. As for (a) smaller groups: Not really, since I need to compute things like Area under Curve that require the full set of predicted and realized values to calculate it. As for (b) I don't know what you mean, which database file type are you thinking of?

Comment: @r2evans
Nice to cu again.
About `dtplyr`, a good bet as it allows interaction with `arrow` tables. But am I right in saying `arrow` tables won't allow `data.table` syntax ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure ... there's (for instance) `arrow::arrow_table`, and there's `dtplyr::lazy_dt`, I'm wondering (with no testing yet) if there's a way to use `dtplyr` to do lazy operations on lazy data using `data.table`'s referential semantics. That may be crossing the streams.

Comment: I don't think `dtplyr` is the solution. `dtplyr` is a way to use the data.table backend with dplyr syntax. OP wants to retain data.table syntax while using whatever backend works. You could try a [feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) for int64 backed indices.